# How to recover a core data document when its state is UIDocumentStateSavingError.

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uimanageddocument

I am using a file as the repo of my core-data. When trying to open it, I get a failure with the document state set to integer 5 (UIDocumentStateSavingError & UIDocumentStateClosed). How do I recover such a document, either by resolving the error or forcing the document to open as is.

Comment: I am in the same boat. From time to time I get in this state but when I continue to edit the document and wait for it to kick off another save it seems everything works itself out but it does have me concerned when it happens.